# Disallow duplicate entry in AngularJS ngList

Tags: angularjs

How can I prevent duplicate entries in AngularJS ng-list?

```
<textarea ng-model="list" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
```

```
{{ list | json }}
```

Comment: Use unique filter for that

Answer (score 0):

Utilize unique filter for this :

> This is general logic to use filter just example, you have to play around it for your logic.

```
 app.filter('unique', function() {
        return function (data, item) {
            return _.uniq(data, function(items) { return items[item]; });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

By using **ng-list** it is not possible to remove duplicate entries. The use of *ng-list* is differ. If you want to remove duplicate entries then go for **ng-repeat** with **custom filter**.